# Npm getting permission errors

Tags: node.js, npm, ssh, file-permissions, node-modules

when I try to globally install any modules, I receive the following error...

```
[Bot (9)] npm install -g miscord
 /home/myhome/nodevenv/Bot/9/bin/npm: line 14: /bin/ln: Permission denied
```

I can install locally, and from what I understood there is no ln folder or script, additionally, it's not writing the miscord folder or files. I am running Nodejs in an environment where I do not have root permissions however it is setup via CPanel, Nodenv and with ssh access. I have tried a few different modules all giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your specific permissions for npm  `sudo npm -g config set user YourUser` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config.html